# What I am missing is this Django "logout"?

Tags: django, logout, django-login

I am new to Django, and I am trying to put the logout to work...

I have installed the an App called, Django-Registration.

My problem is that I can do the logout, but the page does not get refreshed, I must to press F5 after the logout to see the page for not logged users.

What I have done is the following:

**urls.py, added to urlpatterns:**

```
url(r'^logout/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', {'next_page': '/'}, name='auth_logout'),
url(r'^logout/(?P<next_page>.*)/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.logout', name='auth_logout_next'),
```

**In the template I have this code:**

```
{% if request.user.is_authenticated %}
    <p>Welcome {{ request.user.username }}. <a href="{% url auth_logout_next 'directorio' %}">Logout</a></p>
{% else %}
    <p>Welcome. Please <a href="/accounts/login/">login</a> or <a href="/accounts/register/">register</a></p>
{% endif %}
```

When I click **Logout** I dont see this in the screen:

```
<p>Welcome. Please <a href="/accounts/login/">login</a> or <a href="/accounts/register/">register</a></p>
```

I only see this text if I use F5 to refresh the page.

What I am missing here?

Please give me a clue.

Best Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to change order of url patterns - auth_logout_next should be before auth_logout.

Comment: I'm curious why the order of the URLs matters.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<a href="{% url auth_logout_next %}/directorio/">Logout</a>
```

Comment: Well dont work that way, but works if I out in this way "<a href="{% url auth_logout_next '/directorio/' %}">Logout</a>". But this creates a link like "httpd://localhost/logout//directorio//", have twoo(//). Is this correct?